# Adjust/scale landscape table to fit in a4

Tags: tables, scale

I'm trying to adjust my landscape table to fit in the A4 paper margin but as you can see it doesn't seem to work. Even by scaling the table to text width doesn't work as the table will just become super small like in the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Here's my MWE :

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs,lscape}
    \begin{document}   
        \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[]
        \caption{My caption}
        \label{my-label}
        \begin{tabular}{llllllll}
        \hline
        Building Product    & Product                              & Reference Model  & Company                                         & Country of origin & Distance from Port to Singapore (km) & Import & Remarks/Assumptions                                                                                                      \\ \hline
        BIPV facade         & stonewool                            & RL940            & ROCKWOOL Building Materials (Singapore) Pte Ltd & Singapore         & -                                    & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & lightweight concrete                 & -                & -                                               & Malaysia          &                                      & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & gypsum plasterboard                  & StandardCORE     & BORAL Plasterboard                              & Thailand          & 1504                                 & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & BIPV module                          & asi-OPAK         & Schott                                          & Germany           & 16532                                & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & aluminium frame                      & Schueco FW50     & Schuco International KG                         & Germany           & 16532                                & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
        Column              & reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & formwork                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
        Conventional facade & stonewool                            & RL940            & ROCKWOOL Building Materials (Singapore) Pte Ltd & Singapore         &                                      & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & single glazing                       & Stopray Titanium & AGC Asia                                        & Belgium           & 16036                                & YES    & Data found from TUV certified company list                                                                               \\
                            & lightweight concrete                 &                  &                                                 & Singapore         &                                      & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
        Core                & reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & formwork                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               &                   &                                      & NO     & Produced in Singapore                                                                                                    \\
        Drywall             & Paint                                & Nippon           & Nipppon                                         & Singapore         & -                                    & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & Metal substructure (secondary steel) & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         &                                      & NO     & Secondary steel, produced locally through electric arc furnace                                                           \\
                            & gypsum plasterboard                  & standardcore     & BORAL Plasterboardr                             & Thailand          & 1504                                 & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & Glass wool                           & TI-1500          & U.P. Twiga Fiberglass Limited                   & India             & 5161                                 & YES    & Kandla to Singapore                                                                                                      \\
        Foundation          & reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & formwork                             & -                &                                                 & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
        Roof                & insulation polystyrene foam slab     & Insu Slab 500 HD & Uniseal Creative Solutions Pte Ltd              &                   & -                                    & NO     & Produced in Singapore                                                                                                    \\
                            & gravel (aggregate)                   & -                & -                                               &                   &                                      & YES    & Imported from Malaysia                                                                                                   \\
                            & fiberglass felts                     & TI-1500          & U.P. Twiga Fiberglass Limited                   & India             &                                      & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         &                                                 & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
                            & asphalt saturant                     &                  &                                                 &                   &                                      &        &                                                                                                                          \\
        Slab                & Reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & HDPE                                 & Cobiax           & Tiong Seng                                      &                   &                                      & YES    & Raw material imported from Germany                                                                                       \\
                            & formwork                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
        Window              & double glazing                       & Stopray Titanium & AGC Asia                                        & Belgium           & 16036                                & YES    & Data found from TUV certified company list                                                                               \\
                            & aluminium frame                      & Schueco FW50     & Schuco International KG                         & Germany           & 16532                                & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to save some space, you might want to consider getting rid of the last column and use table notes instead. Especially, because there are some repetitive and long entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `longtable` and `threeparttablex` you could achieve the following table that fits onto 2 pages:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs,lscape,longtable, threeparttablex}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

    \begin{document}   
        \begin{landscape}
        \small
 \begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
  \item[a] Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore
  \item[b] No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed
  \item[c] Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore
  \item[d] Data found from TUV certified company list
  \item[e] Secondary steel, produced locally through electric arc furnace 
  \item[f] Produced in Singapore                                                                                                    
  \item[g] Kandla to Singapore
  \item[h] Imported from Malaysia                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  \item[i]  Raw material imported from Germany                                                                                      
  \end{TableNotes}


\begin{longtable}{lL{3cm}lL{4cm}lL{2cm}l}
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
   \endlastfoot
        \toprule
        Building Product    & Product                              & Reference Model  & Company                                         & Country of origin & Distance from Port to Singapore (km) & Import                                                                                                      
         \\ \midrule
 \endhead
        BIPV facade         & stonewool                            & RL940            & ROCKWOOL Building Materials (Singapore) Pte Ltd & Singapore         & -                                    & NO                                                                                                                               \\
                            & lightweight concrete                 & -                & -                                               & Malaysia          &                                      & YES                                                                                                                              \\
                            & gypsum plasterboard                  & StandardCORE     & BORAL Plasterboard                              & Thailand          & 1504                                 & YES                                                                                                                              \\
                            & BIPV module                          & asi-OPAK         & Schott                                          & Germany           & 16532                                & YES                                                                                                                              \\
                            & aluminium frame                      & Schueco FW50     & Schuco International KG                         & Germany           & 16532                                & YES                                                                                                                              \\
                            \addlinespace
        Column              & reinforcing steel \tnote{a}                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES                                        \\
                            & formwork \tnote{b}                            & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO                                           \\
                            & concrete \tnote{c}                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES      \\
                            \addlinespace
        Conventional facade & stonewool                            & RL940            & ROCKWOOL Building Materials (Singapore) Pte Ltd & Singapore         &                                      & NO                                                                                                                               \\
                            & single glazing \tnote{d}                       & Stopray Titanium & AGC Asia                                        & Belgium           & 16036                                & YES                                                                                  \\
                            & lightweight concrete                 &                  &                                                 & Singapore         &                                      & NO                                                                                                                               \\
                            \addlinespace
        Core                & reinforcing steel \tnote{a}                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES                                        \\
                            & formwork \tnote{b}                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO                                          \\
                            & concrete \tnote{f}                            & CEM II/B         & -                                               &                   &                                      & NO       \\
                            \addlinespace
        Drywall             & Paint                                & Nippon           & Nipppon                                         & Singapore         & -                                    & NO                                                                                                                              \\
                            & Metal substructure (secondary steel) \tnote{e} & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         &                                      & NO                                                                 \\
                            & gypsum plasterboard                  & standardcore     & BORAL Plasterboardr                             & Thailand          & 1504                                 & YES                                                                                                                              \\
                            & Glass wool \tnote{g}                           & TI-1500          & U.P. Twiga Fiberglass Limited                   & India             & 5161                                 & YES      \\
                            \addlinespace
        Foundation          & reinforcing steel \tnote{a}                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES                                      \\
                            & formwork \tnote{b}                             & -                &                                                 & -                 & -                                    & NO      \\
                            & concrete  \tnote{c}                           & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES     \\
                            \addlinespace
        Roof                & insulation polystyrene foam slab \tnote{f}    & Insu Slab 500 HD & Uniseal Creative Solutions Pte Ltd              &                   & -                                    & NO                                                                                                         \\
                            & gravel (aggregate) \tnote{h}                  & -                & -                                               &                   &                                      & YES      \\
                            & fiberglass felts                     & TI-1500          & U.P. Twiga Fiberglass Limited                   & India             &                                      & YES                                                                                                                              \\
                            & concrete \tnote{c}                            & CEM II/B         &                                                 & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    \\
                            & asphalt saturant                     &                  &                                                 &                                                         &        &                                                                                                                          \\
                            \addlinespace
       Slab                & Reinforcing steel \tnote{a}                   & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES                                      \\
                           & HDPE \tnote{i}                                 & Cobiax           & Tiong Seng                                      &                   &                                      & YES    \\
                           & formwork \tnote{b}                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO                                        \\
                           & concrete \tnote{c}                            & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES     \\
                           \addlinespace
        Window              & double glazing \tnote{d}                       & Stopray Titanium & AGC Asia                                        & Belgium           & 16036                                & YES     \\
                           & aluminium frame                      & Schueco FW50     & Schuco International KG                         & Germany           & 16532                                & YES                                                                                                                             \\ 
        \end{longtable}
 \end{ThreePartTable}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This fits but it isn't really readable, do you have to fit all this on one page?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs,lscape,array}
    \begin{document}   
        \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}
\vspace*{-2cm}
        \caption{My caption}
        \label{my-label}
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
        \begin{tabular}{
@{}
>{\raggedright}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright}p{3cm}
l>{\raggedright}p{3cm}
lll
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}
@{}
}
        \hline
 \hd{Building\\Product}
    & Product                              & Reference Model  & Company                                         & Country of origin & 
\hd{Distance\\ from\\ Port\\ to\\ Singapore\\ (km)} & Import &
\hd{Remarks\\/\\Assumptions}                                                                                                      \\ \hline
        BIPV facade         & stonewool                            & RL940            & ROCKWOOL Building Materials (Singapore) Pte Ltd & Singapore         & -                                    & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & lightweight concrete                 & -                & -                                               & Malaysia          &                                      & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & gypsum plasterboard                  & StandardCORE     & BORAL Plasterboard                              & Thailand          & 1504                                 & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & BIPV module                          & asi-OPAK         & Schott                                          & Germany           & 16532                                & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & aluminium frame                      & Schueco FW50     & Schuco International KG                         & Germany           & 16532                                & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
        Column              & reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & formwork                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
        Conventional facade & stonewool                            & RL940            & ROCKWOOL Building Materials (Singapore) Pte Ltd & Singapore         &                                      & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & single glazing                       & Stopray Titanium & AGC Asia                                        & Belgium           & 16036                                & YES    & Data found from TUV certified company list                                                                               \\
                            & lightweight concrete                 &                  &                                                 & Singapore         &                                      & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
        Core                & reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & formwork                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               &                   &                                      & NO     & Produced in Singapore                                                                                                    \\
        Drywall             & Paint                                & Nippon           & Nipppon                                         & Singapore         & -                                    & NO     &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & Metal substructure (secondary steel) & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         &                                      & NO     & Secondary steel, produced locally through electric arc furnace                                                           \\
                            & gypsum plasterboard                  & standardcore     & BORAL Plasterboardr                             & Thailand          & 1504                                 & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & Glass wool                           & TI-1500          & U.P. Twiga Fiberglass Limited                   & India             & 5161                                 & YES    & Kandla to Singapore                                                                                                      \\
        Foundation          & reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & formwork                             & -                &                                                 & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
        Roof                & insulation polystyrene foam slab     & Insu Slab 500 HD & Uniseal Creative Solutions Pte Ltd              &                   & -                                    & NO     & Produced in Singapore                                                                                                    \\
                            & gravel (aggregate)                   & -                & -                                               &                   &                                      & YES    & Imported from Malaysia                                                                                                   \\
                            & fiberglass felts                     & TI-1500          & U.P. Twiga Fiberglass Limited                   & India             &                                      & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         &                                                 & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
                            & asphalt saturant                     &                  &                                                 &                   &                                      &        &                                                                                                                          \\
        Slab                & Reinforcing steel                    & NatSteel         & NatSteel Holdings Pte Ltd                       & Singapore         & 5043                                 & YES    & Primary steel is imported mostly from China, secondary steel is processed in Singapore                                   \\
                            & HDPE                                 & Cobiax           & Tiong Seng                                      &                   &                                      & YES    & Raw material imported from Germany                                                                                       \\
                            & formwork                             & -                & -                                               & -                 & -                                    & NO     & No data can be found, aluminium is assumed to be produced locally, hence not changed                                     \\
                            & concrete                             & CEM II/B         & -                                               & Malaysia          & -                                    & YES    & Cements (Lafarge Phoenix Malaysia) and aggregates and sand are imported from Malaysia while concrete mixing in Singapore \\
        Window              & double glazing                       & Stopray Titanium & AGC Asia                                        & Belgium           & 16036                                & YES    & Data found from TUV certified company list                                                                               \\
                            & aluminium frame                      & Schueco FW50     & Schuco International KG                         & Germany           & 16532                                & YES    &                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

\vspace*{-2cm}

        \end{table}
        \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```